# Root window jump to front when opening file dialog in child window tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm using `tkinter` in python to make 2 windows in 2 diffrent classes, their root window open a new window and to make the child window to be on top I'm using `lift()`, but when I'm pressing button that open file dialog window, the root window jump to front again, I've tried also to make the child window on top always using `attributes('-topmost', True)` but then it's appearing above the dialog window as well.
How do I make the root window always stays lower and not come back up?

Comment: Pop-up windows usually are supposed to be above all other windows of that process. Can you please provide a minimal working example that shows your problem?

Comment: Have you tried making the popup window a child of the son? Without seeing a [mcve] it's a bit hard for us to know what the problem is.

Comment: You can make the child window a *transient* window of root window: e.g. `child_win.transient(root)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code worked for me. GUI is my toplevel window, and root is my main window.

```
    GUI.attributes('-topmost', 0)
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    GUI.attributes('-topmost', 1)
```

Once the filedialog opens file, I will bring back my GUI window to front.

Answer (score 1):

You can guarantee a child window will have the focus with `filedialog`, like this.

`image = fido.askopenfilename( parent = child, title = "Pick an image" )`

`Transient` applied to child window will make child sit in front of parent but will **not** stop parent from being the focus after loading data.

I've set program so you can test this, just set conditional statement to `True` and by removing `parent = child` from filedialog.

Code has been expanded to fully test `tkinter` behaviour

**Tkinter Experiments:**

Test `Tk` and `Toplevel` windows for focus control and image display when
using `tk.filedialog.askopenfilename`

**Conclusion:**

Unless explicitly set **after** filedialog closes, the final focus will always go to the widget defined in filedialog (default = parent).

Setting child to transient will not affect the final focus.

Also, if child is `tk.Tk()` then tk.PhotoImage requires both `file = image` and `master = parent|child`, otherwise a `_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist` error is thrown.

If child is `tk.Toplevel()` then tk.PhotoImage only requires `file = image` to successfully display photo!

```py
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fido

parent = tk.Tk()
parent.title("Parent")

# Give tkinter time to compute parent size and position
parent.update()

# Extract window dimensions from parent
x, y, w = parent.winfo_x(), parent.winfo_y(), parent.winfo_width()

if False:

    # Create child as `Toplevel`
    child = tk.Toplevel(parent)
    child.title("Child")

    # Test usefulness of transient in controlling focus
    if True:
        child.transient(parent)

else:

    # Create child as `Tk
    child = tk.Tk()
    child.title("Child")

#  Place both windows side by side
child.geometry( f"+{x+w+10}+{y}" )

if False:

    # TEST 1: Focus will ulitmately go to parent
    child.focus_set()
    image = fido.askopenfilename( title = "Pick an image" )

else:

    # TEST 2: Focus will ulitmately go to child
    parent.focus_set()
    image = fido.askopenfilename( parent = child, title = "Pick an image" )

# Demonstrate that placing data (image) in child will not alter the focus
if image:
    if True:

        # Try loading image method #1: Will show image
        photo = tk.PhotoImage(master = child, file = image)

    else:

        # Try loading image method #2: Will throw error
        photo = tk.PhotoImage(file = image)

    # Display photo in `label`
    label = tk.Label(
        child, image = photo, foreground = "white", font = "Consolas 20 normal",
        compound = tk.CENTER, text = os.path.split( image )[1])
    label.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

parent.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is the more appropriate answer. It's more pythonic and focuses on the actual issue at hand instead of "code hacks."